# How to get comma separated values in a text field of a form as values to perform math functions in java script?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am working on this survey form where I have to get user data of 5 comma separated values in text box and the next text box must immediately show the average of the above entered values i.e. dynamically. Please some one help me fix this

Comment: What did you do for yourself to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Heres your code, you shouldn't be lazy in the future!

```
var values = document.getElementsByName('name_of_input')[0].value.split(',');
var sum = 0;
for(var a = 0 ; a < values.length ; a++){
    sum = sum + values[a];
}
var average = sum / values.length;
document.getElementsByName('name_of_next_text_box')[0].value = average;
```